# Wordpress how to load additional stylesheets (charts.css)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'd like to enqueue a stylesheet called `charts.css` & `charts.min.css`.

I'm not sure, why it's not working.

That's my added code in `functions.php` Wordpress:

```
function additional_stylesheets() {
    wp_register_style( 'custom01', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/minified/charts.min.css'  );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom01' );
    wp_register_style( 'custom02', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/unminified/charts.css'  );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom02' );
    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'additional_stylesheets' );
```

I tried in elementor to style a table but nothin' happened.

So I also tried to use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content/themes/astra/assets/css/minified/charts.min.css">
```

but that's also not working.

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

I use the theme astra in WordPress.

The path is `wp-content/themes/astra/`.

After appending styleheets in WordPress I do not have to call them in `html` code anymore am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to register them. Instead use the following code:

```php
function additional_stylesheets() {
  wp_enqueue_style('charts_min_styles', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/css/minified/charts.min.css'), NULL, 1.2, false);
  wp_enqueue_style('charts_styles', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/css/unminified/charts.css'), NULL, 1.2, false);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'additional_stylesheets' );
```

The code goes to the `functions.php` of your active theme or child them.

Comment: hm, still not working, when I wanna use it in my HTML shortcode. Usage says I just should call it in my table `<table class="charts-css">` that should be enough shouldn't it?

Comment: To test if they're loaded or not, right click on your page and click "view page source". Once you are on the "page source" search for "charts_min_styles" or "charts_styles". See  if you can find them in the source. See whether the stylesheets have loaded or not.

Comment: Great advice. they are loaded. Can you give me another useful tip to find out why the sheet is not working?